# Why can't I cast boxed int to nullable decimal?

Tags: c#, .net

Why there is InvalidCastException thrown? Can someone describe me this behavior?

```
object zero = 0;
decimal? dec = (decimal?)zero;
```

Comment: @John Saunders: This is not legal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A boxed `int` can only be unboxed to an `int`. This, however, is legal:

```
object zero = 0;
decimal? dec = (decimal?)(int)zero;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) or the ECMA 334 C# spec for details. The key here is the following:

Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type object to a value type or from an interface type to a value type that implements the interface. An unboxing operation consists of:

1. **Checking the object instance to make sure that it is a boxed value of the given value type.**
2. Copying the value from the instance into the value-type variable.

Edit: This linked [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) is worth pulling out of the comments. Thanks Rob Kennedy!

Comment: Ok, but why such interim casting is necessary?

Comment: The first cast (int) unboxes the boxed int to a value type of type int (this is a legal operation). The second cast (decimal?) casts the resulting int to decimal?.

Comment: Microsoft (for good reason) never wrote a implicit cast overload for object to decimal.

Comment: @Michael Meadows: This is legal: object zero = 0m; decimal? dec = (decimal)zero; Note the 'm' explicitly telling the compiler that the literal "0" is to be interpreted as a decimal.

Comment: @Jason, a decimal is an object, so the first example is polymorphism.  The second example is explicit casting.  What I was saying was to answer @Przemaas' comment.  You must explicitly cast the "zero" variable to int first, because you cannot implicitly cast an object to int, and since it's not an INullable<decimal>, the explicit cast directly to that type fails.

Comment: @Michael Meadows: Either I misread your comment, or you deleted it and changed "explicit" to "implicit." I initially read your comment to state that there was no explicit cast from object to decimal. Apologies if I misread.

Comment: Eric Lippert goes into quite some detail about why this works the way it does. The summary: Unboxing to anything but the original type would involve *a lot* of generated code for all the different possibilities since the compiler doesn't know what the original boxed type is. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: @Rob : I was looking for this post but wasn't able to find it... thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

See this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx

Specifically
"The common language runtime first ensures that the reference type variable is not null and that it refers to an object that is a boxed value of the desired value type. If either test fails, then an InvalidCastException exception is generated."

I think you are failing on the object of that value. I think the coversion to int works because that 0 literal will convert to an int and then an int converts to decimal.

If you do this it works

```
    decimal? test=0;
    object zero = test;
    decimal? dec = (decimal?)zero;
```

But I think the "0" in your snippet is not a "decimal" type.

I am still not positive cause this gets the same exception.

```
        int test=0;
        object zero = test;
        decimal? dec = (decimal?)zero;
```

Comment: My problem originally comes from below method:

public TResult Convert(object value)
{
try { return (TResult)value; }
catch (InvalidCastException) { return default(TResult); }
}

This method returns null when called:
Convert<decimal?>(0);

I cann't make any assumptions about TResult and I don't know what exactly comes as an argument. That is why I cannot use Convert.To...() goodies.